# Use a batch file to send a command to another batch file

Tags: batch-file

I'm currently running a StarMade Server and am working on having the server auto restart.

Right now we have 2 batch files, 1 that runs the server, and another to restart the server.

The batch file running the server is:

---

```
title Main Starmade Server

java -Xms4096m -Xmx6144m -XX:PermSize=512m -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseNUMA -XX:+CMSParallelRemarkEnabled -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=50 -XX:+UseAdaptiveGCBoundary -XX:-UseGCOverheadLimit -XX:+UseBiasedLocking -XX:SurvivorRatio=8 -XX:TargetSurvivorRatio=90 -XX:UseSSE=3 -XX:+UseLargePages -XX:+UseFastAccessorMethods -XX:+UseStringCache -XX:+UseCompressedOops -XX:+AggressiveOpts -verbose:gc -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -XX:+PrintTenuringDistribution -Xloggc:memory.log -Xincgc -Xshare:off -jar StarMade.jar -server

EXIT
```

---

And the batch file restarting the server is:

---

```
   @echo off
              title Server Automated Restarter
       :start
        echo Starting Starmade Server
              set time=60
        set timer
      cd C:\StarMade\StarMade
              start StartServer.bat /REALTIME
        timeout 120
        echo Server Started
        timeout 5
       :loop
              cls
              IF %time% GTR 0 (
               set /a time=%time% -1
               set /a min=%time%/60 +1
                 echo Server Restarter Active
                 echo Next Restart In %time% Seconds; Less Than %min% Minutes Remaining
        cd C:\Windows\System32
        ping (my ip goes here, but I've removed it for this post) -n 2 > NUL
              goto loop
              )
    echo Killing Java Task
    timeout 5 
       taskkill /f /im java.exe
    timeout 30
    echo Restarting Starmade Server 
      cls
     goto start
```

---

Obviously, this technically crashes the server is it is force stopped. The game has a "`/force_save"` command and a `"/shutdown (timeInSec)"` command. I would like to be able to use the automated restarter bat to send those commands to the other batch file which is running the server. While the server is running, no other commands and be called within the batch file running the server (unless manually typed).

Comment: Im not sure about sending a command but you can communicate accross batch files with either a yes or a no using the `waitfor` command (If you're using windows 7)

Comment: To clarify, I want to replace the code for ending the java process with code that can send the server a "/force_save" and "/shutdown" command.